# How do I go through mysql results to create multiple lines of 1 line?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm automating a schedule, but I do not know what to do now.

I have a list of orders, of an order I want to know the ID, the internal delivery date, the number of baths and the working date. The ID and the internal delivery date I can request and the number of baths are calculated by dividing the price of the order by 125.

2 baths per order can be done in one day and the order must be done on the internal_delivery_date. There may be 2 baths on 1 work date multiple times but not from the same order it is more about the order being processed in parts.

What I have:

```
SELECT ROUND(total_without_vat /125, 2) AS Baths, ID, internal_delivery_date 
FROM Orders
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GweP9.png)

What I want:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4PZW.png)

Create script:

```
create table Orders(
   ID INT NOT NULL,
   internal_delivery_date date NOT NULL,
   total_without_vat decimal(16,2) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( ID )
);
INSERT INTO Orders (ID, internal_delivery_date, total_without_vat)
VALUES ('17633', '2019-02-14', '400.01');
INSERT INTO Orders (ID, internal_delivery_date, total_without_vat)
VALUES ('17835', '2019-02-21', '1156.48');
INSERT INTO Orders (ID, internal_delivery_date, total_without_vat)
VALUES ('18051', '2019-02-28', '386.50');
```

How can I do this?

Comment: By dividing by 125? You can. But why would you? Just store the quantity ordered.